# aligning image/sprite to show top and bottom half

Tags: css, image, sprite

I am trying to position an image so the bottom half is the inverse of the top from one image but not sure how to do it.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobeeornot/JvnHn/)

The image itself looks like [this](http://i1200.photobucket.com/albums/bb328/tobeeornot/sec.png).

EDIT: The final image should look like [this.](http://i1200.photobucket.com/albums/bb328/tobeeornot/section.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS `section.sep h3.top` should be `section.sep h4.top` because you have used `h4` in HTML instead of `h3`

Your HTML :

```
<section class="sep">
    <h4 class="top company-tag">Pics</h4>
    <hr/>
    <h4 class="bottom company-tag">Map</h4>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction but that makes no difference to the image.

Comment: See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/JvnHn/6/ Some changes in css markup

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this but i want the top part of the image to remain that way and the bottom half to flipped vertically to reflect the bottom part of the image.

Comment: Please see Edit above for what final image should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define the height and line-height in your **section.sep h4**
 and its working fine now as per your requirement..

**CSS**

```
section.sep h4{
  background: url('http://i1200.photobucket.com/albums/bb328/tobeeornot/sec.png') no-repeat transparent;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 69px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 77px;
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/JvnHn/7/

Comment: thanks but that is not right either. i only want half of the top of the image to cover 'pics' and the bottom half of the image to cover 'map'.

Comment: Please see Edit above for what final image should look like.